# How to position certain sections within an article

Tags: html, css

I have 3 sections within an article, I have the first 2 side by side at 40% width each.  One float left, and another right.  I cannot get the third section id: interests, to be centered below the 2.  I want some margin top to give some space.  Also when I minimize the screen it also drops into the footer.  Any suggestions, thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/sy8o4vbt/

```
 #interests {
    width: 90%;
    border: thin solid #000000;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: 103px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: You need `clear: both;` for a start, but otherwise it renders as you describe for me! You need to put `margin-bottom` on one (or both) of the two side by side items too.

Comment: Thanks...that seems to help...how can i keep the bottom section from running into footer when screen size minimizes?

Comment: I can't reproduce that, but you may need to position the footer absolute (and `bottom: 0`), and make sure there's enough padding on the bottom element so it's not overlapping.

Comment: I feel like I should be able to set a margin bottom to keep the space I need...nothing is happening with a margin bottom set

Answer (score -1):

fixed this with appropriate CSS:

```
#interests {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#interest_inner_div{
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

JSFiddle Link    http://jsfiddle.net/7mzp80gg/

Comment: Note that this is just one of the million ways it can be fixed.

Comment: Please let me know why its down voted, so that I cam improve or correct my answer.